# Validator pushed TextFormField above

Tags: flutter

I tried creating an email textfield with validator using [`TextFormField`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html). Since the textfield height is too much for my liking, I wrap the `TextFormField` with `Container` and set the `height` to 50. Now the problem is whenever I submitted intended wrong value, the validator will popped out and pushed the textfield, leaving the height much smaller than what I set in `Container`.

**Before submitting:**

[image: Before submitting]

**After submitting:**

[image]

Here is my codes:

```dart
Widget _emailForm() {
    return Form(
      key: _emailFormKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text("Enter Your Email", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0),),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            child: TextFormField(
              focusNode: _emailFocusNode,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              controller: _emailTextController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(0.0),),
                ),
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  iconSize: 16.0,
                  icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if(_emailTextController != null) {
                        _emailTextController.clear();
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_emailFocusNode);
                    }
                  },
                ),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(0.0),
                  ),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    width: 1.0
                  )
                ),
                errorStyle: _errorTextStyle,
              ),
              validator: (val) {
                Pattern pattern = r'@';
                RegExp regex = RegExp(pattern);
                if(val.isEmpty) return "* Email address can't be empty";
                else if(!regex.hasMatch(val)) return "* Invalid email address";
                else {
                  return null;
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0),),
          FlatButton(
            child: Text("Join".toUpperCase(), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 11),),
            onPressed: (){
              if(_emailFormKey.currentState.validate()) {
                _joinWaitingList();
              }
            },
            color: _themeColor,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

This widget is part of `ListView` in my `build` method if that information is helping. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that TextField and TextFormField size themselves to include all of their content and decoration. If you add some error text onto the bottom of the TextFormField, then it will include that in its height.  When it tries to size itself to fit into your Container, it doesn't have as much space for the input.

You could work around this by specifying the height of your Container in both the valid and invalid states.  You'll have to fiddle with the exact invalid height, but it might look something like this:

```dart
Container(
  height: _isInvalid ? 100 : 50,
  TextFormField(),
),
```

Another option is to add `counterText: ' '` to your InputDecoration and then size the Container to the size that you want.  This will give you extra space to fit the error text without needing to change the height of the TextFormField.

```dart
Container(
  height: 100,
  TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      counterText: ' ',
    ),
  ),
),
```

The cleanest solution, if it's possible for you, may be to not use a Container at all.  If you can create the input you want just by using InputDecoration and things like `contentPadding` etc., it will likely make this a lot cleaner.

Comment: Nice answer. the TextFormField default size is too big I find, especially for web. Wish there was another way to make the height smaller without fiddling with it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

hey i think that its works if u use onchanged instead of validator :

```
 onChanged: (val) {
                Pattern pattern = r'@';
                RegExp regex = RegExp(pattern);
                if(val.isEmpty) return "* Email address can't be empty";
                else if(!regex.hasMatch(val)) return "* Invalid email address";
                else {
                  return null;
                }
              },
```

Comment: The `onChanged` argument to `TextFormField` is a `ValueChanged` type (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueChanged.html) which must return void. You suggestion won't work.